# Display data from phpMyAdmin with WordPress

Tags: query, sql, phpmyadmin

I have imported my website to Wordpress and facing a big issue how can I do sql Query to display data on my pages with wordpress?
for example I have product, price, description which I need to display on the web site, how can I do ?

Comment: Are these in custom tables? Or are these post meta/custom fields etc? Is the data in the same database or a separate/remote database?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to query from the same database in which your WordPress is installed then there is a great way to do sql query with ease. WordPress has a database access abstraction class called `wpdb` that allows you to run raw mysql query without any issue.

You can start using it like one of two methods bellow:

```
// 1st Method - Declaring $wpdb as global and using it to execute an SQL query statement that returns a PHP object
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}options WHERE option_id = 1", OBJECT );
```

or

```
// 2nd Method - Utilizing the $GLOBALS superglobal. Does not require global keyword ( but may not be best practice )
$results = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}options WHERE option_id = 1", OBJECT );
```

Explore the documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) and get started!

Answer (score 0):

If it is third party DB you can first connect and then fetch results

```
mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select Name from my_table");
```

if it is local db , you can use global wpdb object as well.

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}options WHERE option_id = 1", OBJECT );
```

for reference.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/

you can run the above code in functions.php.

Depending upon your requirement you can hook it with some action or add it as a shortcode.

e.g.

```
add_shortcode( 'dbresults', 'wp_dbresutls' );
function wp_dbresutls( ) {
 // your db code
 }
```